# Функция не видит аргумент в GO

Tags: golang

Изучаю Go, в курсе столкнулся с проблемой что функция не видит передаваемый аргумент.
Упростил и вынес в отдельный проект, но ошибка осталась.
Ошибка `undeclared name: servProd`

Структура проекта

```
test
├─ go.mod
├─ internal
│  └─ handler
│     ├─ opkg.go
│     └─ pl.go
└─ main.go
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функция  listCommand принимает тип указатель servProd, но нигде не описан сам этот тип, но есть тип Service, который возвращает NewService?!

Comment: Да, спасибо, вчера разобрался